# Enter key not working in terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, keyboard-layout

Just now, the enter key has stopped working in a terminal only. 
Works in all other apps, but only generates the default system sound when pressed in the terminal.

Tried both xTerm and gnome-terminal, tried restarting.

No joy.

I'm at a loss, because I can't use the terminal to resolve this. It doesn't even work when I use CTRL-ALT-F2 to toggle to a full terminal outside X.

Anyone have any ideas?

All I can think of to do is open bash related configs and clear them after backing them up, but I'd prefer any better ideas.
Being unable to grep or find anything is a large limitation.

This is in Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: press Ctrl-V and the the Enter Key. What shows up?

Comment: Pressing CTRL-V and Enter gives ^M

Answer (score 1):

Open

> Preferences -> shortcuts

in terminal:

[image: open preferences -> shortcuts in terminal]

Then

1. Single click on copy shortcuts
2. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on window simultaneously
4. Close the preferences and your enter key will work.

Comment: Preferences -> shortcuts >> Disabled worked for me ( Actual problem was 'Copy as HTML' shortcut was   somehow replaced with 'Return' key, Just double clicked there and hit backspace once to change it back to 'Disable' state )

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it was something in the generated .profile file. But I don't see what was wrong.

I'm posting this as "Answered", but in case anyone wants to see, here are the contents of .profile; I don't see anything wrong, myself:

```
    # ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
    # This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
    # exists.
    # see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
    # the files are located in the bash-doc package.

    # the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
    # for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
    #umask 022

    # if running bash
    if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
        # include .bashrc if it exists
        if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
        fi
    fi

    # set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
    if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
        PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
    fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell from that profile, but ensure that you do not leave a empty line at the end. I had this issue with my .bashrc that kept the enter key from working properly.

Comment: Makes no sense. Both `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc` are shell script files, and empty lines at the bottom shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: I agree that it doesn't make sense, but I had a similar problem. The Enter key worked in tcsh, but not in bash. As soon as I removed the last empty line in .inputrc it started working again.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, in case somebody stumbles here, searching for answers...
Another thing to try is the Enter key on the *keypad*, if you have a full size keyboard. The (Logitech 270R) keyboard was working fine under Win, so nothing wrong with the key itself. (I didn't have an alternate Linux installation to try, at the time.)
In my case, the normal Enter didn't work but the keypad did. It was on an ARM box, though.